# How to convert keystore to older version

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, jks

I have problem with building keystore jks.

I have a key that was generated using the following command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
```

The problem is that I cant use this key as it gives me error:

> Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:
> Algorithm HmacPBESHA256

As far as I understand this is due to jdk 11 not supporting this. I tried upgrading to newer jdk but android studio flutter does not appear to accept any other jdk other than 11 when compiling.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98072

The key command that works in the android studio flutter is the following:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

Since I am unable to create new Pem file I am trying to convert the key from the first command to second one
I know its possible to import using something like this:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

but pkcs12 is not support either and I am unsure how to figure out how to make it same as previous one
The error I get when converted specifically to pkcs12 is the following:

> Warning: The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended
> to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using
> "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore upload-keystore.jks
> -destkeystore upload-keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".

So essentially what I am trying to do is.
Make key that uses the same PEM as the one that is upload to google play.
I have key which is linked to it already so if I can somehow duplicate it at lower encryption level as shown in the example that works that would do too.
Alternative solutions are also welcome.